# How to interchange between (embedded) Raven db 3.5 License string and License.xml file

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, licensing, ravendb-studio

I have a license.xml file from Raven db containing my license. But at the moment instead of a License.xml file I use a License string in my source code. My question is that how can I get License string for my current License.xml file to add into my source code. Also how can I check my current license details from a license string from my source code. I tried reading the documentation but I couldn't find anything on this topic.

e.g I have something like the following for license configuration in my source code:

```
public static Action<RavenConfiguration> GetConfiguration(string path){
            if (path == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            return x =>
            {
                x.DataDirectory = path;
                x.AssembliesDirectory = Path.Combine(path, "Assemblies");
                x.CompiledIndexCacheDirectory = Path.Combine(path, "CompiledIndexCacheDirectory");

                x.Settings["Raven/Licensing/AllowAdminAnonymousAccessForCommercialUse"] = "true";
                x.Settings["Raven/License"] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String( "asaascascasfacscscscsdsdfdvsfvdvfsdsvs"+
                                          "asaascascasfacscscscsdsdfdvsfvdvfsdsvs"+
                                          "asaascascasfacscscscsdsdfdvsfvdvfsdsvs"+
                                          "asaascascasfacscscscsdsdfdvsfvdvfsdsvs"+
                                          "asaascascasfacscscscsdsdfdvsfvdvfsdsvs"+
                                          "asaascascasfacscscscsdsdfdvsfvdvfsdsvs"));
            };
}
```